# Iron-router ReferenceError: AppController is not defined

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using iron-router in my Meteor app but each time I try to add a new sub-controller to my AppController I get the following error. Below is the router related code in my application, can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

```
 /Users/mkm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.n80bjt++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
         throw(ex);
           ^
ReferenceError: AppController is not defined
    at app/both/controllers/aboutus.js:1:56
    at app/both/controllers/aboutus.js:5:3
    at /Users/mkm/meteor/projects/mshop/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
```

Code I am using in my app:

```
AppController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'appLayout'
});
HomeController = AppController.extend({

});
DashboardController = AppController.extend({

});
AboutUsController = AppController.extend({  

});


Router.configure({
  controller: 'AppController',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});


Router.map(function() {

  this.route('home', {
     path: '/',
     template: 'home',
     controller: "HomeController"        
  });

  this.route('aboutus', {
     path: '/aboutus',
     template: 'aboutus',
     controller: "AboutUsController"    
  });

  this.route('dashboard', {
     path: '/dashboard',
     template: 'dashboard',
     controller: "DashboardController"     
  });

});
```

Versions:

iron:router@1.0.7

Meteor 1.0.3.1

Comment: I added your code above to a single file and it worked fine. I have these packages installed: autopublish 1.0.2,
insecure         1.0.2,
iron:router      1.0.7,
meteor           1.1.4,
meteor-platform  1.2.1. Try running `meteor list` to compare. Also, does this error occur after starting meteor or after accessing a route?

Comment: It occurs after starting meteor and it won't allow you to go any further as the app crash. On a minor note, I tried renaming AboutUsController to MAboutUsController and it worked!! With few more tests I noticed that as long as the new controllers names follow AppController alphabetically everything is working fine, else it crash...So for example if I named the new controller BppController it will work...but AooController won't work...so I was wondering does this have to do anything with the sequence those files are compiled by Meteor?

Comment: That's an interesting find. I'm not familiar with a fix, but would suggest you create an issue on the repo: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues. Hopefully someone can help you there. If you could post the link to the Github issue here it might help others, too. HTH.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. And as you say renaming to something that is alphabetically is a work around